# Visual Studio 2005 Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, compiler-errors

Im currently debugging a webservice written in visual studio 2005, however when i build it, it has an error but it did not specify anything

Error   1   The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

[error message can be seen here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?180ed4e446.png)

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?180ed4e446.png>http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.180ed4e446.png alt="Free Image Hosting by FreeImageHosting.net">

Badly needed your help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this error before. I managed to build the solution by deleting some 3rd party dlls in the bin folder. I am still not sure what is happening behind the scenes but it worked. :D

Comment: It's the result of a missing dependency in one of those dlls.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this http://forums.asp.net/p/939729/1121085.aspx. There several post on related exception, might be able to help you.